# Is it a good idea to keep updating users current location?

Tags: ios, swift, memory, location

In my app I have to send a Lat/Long to my server and in return I get an array of Data within the range of 10-15m and I have to add the people on the map. I can achieve this by few different scenarios:

1- I can load all the Data within the range of 100m and only make a request if user searches outside this range.

2- I can use the method "startUpdatingLocation" whenever user searches for a location and when user is on that location I can call "stopUpdatingLocation". The Last location will be saved and used to send for the request.

3- Or I can keep the location updating and when user clicks on the button to make the request I can get the last lat/lang.

They might sound similar but I want to know which scenario saves less memory and data usage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on how often the users are performing searches, and if their searches are geographically close to one another. Approach #1 uses more memory because it has to store a larger array of data (which, depending on what the data looks like, probably isn't a very big deal) but it might save data usage in the long run if you have to perform less queries to your server. It depends on user behavior.

Approaches #2 and #3 don't seem to be any different in terms of data usage and memory since you are describing different ways of keeping the latitude and longitude of an user updated. This doesn't seem to be related to the data usage of your server.

Comment: Hmm user will probably make 10-15 requests but searches are probably close to each other